# Multiple apps in one "icon" on the iPod touch

Tags: ipod-touch

I have researched but can't find any discussion about moving several apps into one "icon" on the iPod touch screen. I have moved 5 apps (all the same category) into one what is normally one app icon.  The title on the icon reads "games" - all are games.  I have  all the apps jiggling and drag one game app on top of another game app - They move to be side by side and the title automatically reads "games" - is this "OK" to do - you can have nine apps in each of the 16 spaces available on each screen.  Will this hurt the touch?  As long as you have space (GBs) is this ok?  Has anyone done or heard of this?  Any help is appriecated.

Comment: http://www.apple.com/iphone/features/folders.html and Folders can hold up to 12 apps - but only shows 9 in the mini-icon. Also, sadly this doesn't belong on Super User.

Answer (score 1):

This is a new feature in iPhone O/S 4. It's by design and has no impact on storage space.